# Can I Call An Excel Formula in a Literal Array

Tags: excel, excel-formula, syntax

I am writing a lightweight VBA parser for Excel formulae.  I need to know if there exists *any* syntactically valid way, in an Excel formula, to call a function within a literal array

```swift
= 2 * {SUM(1, 3); 5; 6}
```

which would yield the same result as:

```swift
= 2 * {4; 5; 6}
```

In other words, I need to know if a function call `FUN()` — or indeed any parenthetical group like `(1 + 3)` — is ever permitted between two braces `{` and `}` in an Excel formula.  Here the braces — or whatever [`xlLeftBrace`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.xlapplicationinternational) and [`xlRightBrace`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.xlapplicationinternational) are locally used for array literals — must be syntactically "active", rather than contained in (say) a literal string `"text with {braces} inside"`.

I know this is a simple question, but I've been unable to find or verify a **universal answer**.  For what it's worth, I've tried it in Excel (`16.64`) for Mac (Monterey `12.3.1`), and it generated a syntax error.

Comment: Do you mean in a formula or in VBA?

Comment: @P.b In a formula.  Apologies for the ambiguity.  I have clarified the question accordingly.

Comment: You can't, but you may use workaround like `=2*CHOOSE({1;2;3},SUM(1,3),5,6)`

Comment: @P.b Good to know.  As long as a function call `FUN(...)` _absolutely cannot_ exist within an array literal `{...}`, then my parser should be fine.

Comment: From MS Help: Array constants can contain numbers, text, logical values (such as TRUE and FALSE), and error values such as #N/A. You can use numbers in integer, decimal, and scientific formats. If you include text, you need to surround it with quotation marks ("text”).  In other words, you cannot use formulas or functions.

Comment: Thanks, @RonRosenfeld!  I'm guessing that means `= {1; NA()}` is an invalid formula, even though the `NA()` function yields the `#N/A` value?

Comment: What happened when you tried it?

Comment: @RonRosenfeld It failed, as expected.  I just want to be sure that this behavior is universal.

Comment: That is correct.  `NA()` is a function.  It is not a number, text, logical value, or error value.  It does not behave any differently than any other function so far as being includable as an element of an array constant.  I didn't understand why you thought it might behave differently than other functions that yield an includable type.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld _"I didn't understand why you thought it might behave differently than other functions that yield an includable type."_  The proper conclusion certainly seemed logical to me, but as a newbie to MS frameworks with only a Mac for testing purposes, I've learned to double-check my "logical" assumptions about "universal" rules.  This becomes doubly important for writing a parser, where a single wrong assumption can throw everything into absolute chaos.

Comment: Yes, there is a saying, applicable to many fields, that "*logic has no place in ...*" And MS documentation has been known not to be entirely accurate in some instances. But I believe it is accurate in this case. One can never be 100% certain, though. Even developers/coders may wonder from time to time: "*What the heck is it doing now?*"